# Jinja2 How to return one match in a for

Tags: for-loop, jinja2, home-assistant

I've little knowledge developing, I've spent days looking for a solution for this, doing tests and nothing.

I have in Home Assistant, a rest sensor, who gives a JSON with unsorted data of all the gas stations in my area, this is part of it:

```json
{
   "Fecha": "22/03/2022 12:10:11",
   "ListaEESSPrecio": [
      {
         "C.P.": "09003",
         "Dirección": "CL GENERAL SANZ PASTOR, S.N.",
         "Horario": "L-V: 08:00-16:00",
         "Latitud": "42,344667",
         "Localidad": "BURGOS",
         "Longitud (WGS84)": "-3,698667",
         "Margen": "D",
         "Municipio": "Burgos",
         "PrecioProducto": "1,789",
         "Provincia": "BURGOS",
         "Remisión": "OM",
         "Rótulo": "REPSOL",
         "Tipo Venta": "P",
         "IDEESS": "5989",
         "IDMunicipio": "1220",
         "IDProvincia": "09",
         "IDCCAA": "08"
      },
      {
         "C.P.": "09001",
         "Dirección": "LOPEZ BRAVO, 93",
         "Horario": "L-V: 06:30-22:00; S: 08:00-14:30",
         "Latitud": "42,362528",
         "Localidad": "BURGOS",
         "Longitud (WGS84)": "-3,762083",
         "Margen": "D",
         "Municipio": "Burgos",
         "PrecioProducto": "1,798",
         "Provincia": "BURGOS",
         "Remisión": "dm",
         "Rótulo": "VILLALÓN",
         "Tipo Venta": "P",
         "IDEESS": "9803",
         "IDMunicipio": "1220",
         "IDProvincia": "09",
         "IDCCAA": "08"
      },
      {
         "C.P.": "09001",
         "Dirección": "CALLE CONDADO DE TREVIÑO, 30",
         "Horario": "L-D: 06:00-00:00",
         "Latitud": "42,370528",
         "Localidad": "BURGOS",
         "Longitud (WGS84)": "-3,718528",
         "Margen": "I",
         "Municipio": "Burgos",
         "PrecioProducto": "1,792",
         "Provincia": "BURGOS",
         "Remisión": "dm",
         "Rótulo": "VILLALONQUEJAR",
         "Tipo Venta": "P",
         "IDEESS": "11878",
         "IDMunicipio": "1220",
         "IDProvincia": "09",
         "IDCCAA": "08"
      }]
}
```

Then in home assistant I have a lovelace card to show the data of the 5 cheapest gas stations, the code is like this:

[image: example of card]

```yaml
- name: Gasolinera 1 nombre
  value_template: "{{ value_json['ListaEESSPrecio'][0]['Rótulo'] }}"
- name: Gasolinera 1 precio
  value_template: "{{ value_json['ListaEESSPrecio'][0]['PrecioProducto'] }}"
  unit_of_measurement: "€"
- name: Gasolinera 1 dirección
  value_template: "{{ value_json['ListaEESSPrecio'][0]['Dirección'] }}"
```

As you can see I have to created for each gas station, it's related data on the JSON.

To sort the JSON I tested this, that works:

```
{% for item in ListaEESSPrecio | sort(attribute='PrecioProducto') %}
    {{ item.Rótulo, item.PrecioProducto, item.Dirección }}
{%- endfor %}
```

This gives me all the JSON data sorted, I selected too the fields I'm interested in:

```
('REPSOL', '1,789', 'CL GENERAL SANZ PASTOR, S.N.')
('VILLALONQUEJAR', '1,792', 'CALLE CONDADO DE TREVIÑO, 30')
('VILLALÓN', '1,798', 'LOPEZ BRAVO, 93')
```

Now the problem, is how to access only to one item of all the dict or array for putting it on the lovelace card, where I select each sensor data to the data on the JSON. gas_station1.price = in JSON data the first sorted gas station.

I have tested things like these, but with no luck.

```
{% for item in value_json['ListaEESSPrecio'][0] | sort(attribute='PrecioProducto') %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        {{ item.Rótulo, item.PrecioProducto, item.Dirección }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
{% for item in ListaEESSPrecio | sort(attribute='PrecioProducto') if item[0] <= t <= item[1]  %}
  {{ item[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

The last trial gives the error:

> `UndefinedError: dict object has no element 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to achieve that, you can use the [`first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.first) filter after you have applied your `sort` filter to pull only one item out of your list:

```
{% set item = ListaEESSPrecio | sort(attribute='PrecioProducto') | first %}
{{ item['Rótulo'], item['PrecioProducto'], item['Dirección'] }}
```

Or, use the square brackets notation `[ ]` to access a specific item of your list *— mind that a Python list always start at the index `0`*:

```
{% set item = (ListaEESSPrecio | sort(attribute='PrecioProducto'))[0] %}
{{ item['Rótulo'], item['PrecioProducto'], item['Dirección'] }}
```

---

*Mind that, because you do have Spanish accents in the property names of your dictionary, you might have to use the square brackets notation `[ ]` to access those property too.*

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You made my day!
About the square brackets notation, they already correctly applied isn't they? ```item['Rótulo']```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your results sorted on the value of PrecioProducto:
use sort(attribute=1.<dict_key>)

Then with the json like this:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(coffee, indent=4))
{
    "Fecha": "22/03/2022 12:10:11",
    "ListaEESSPrecio": [
        {
            "C.P.": "09003",
            "Direcci\u00f3n": "CL GENERAL SANZ PASTOR, S.N.",
            "Horario": "L-V: 08:00-16:00",
            "Latitud": "42,344667",
            "Localidad": "BURGOS",
            "Longitud (WGS84)": "-3,698667",
            "Margen": "D",
            "Municipio": "Burgos",
            "PrecioProducto": "1,789",
            "Provincia": "BURGOS",
            "Remisi\u00f3n": "OM",
            "R\u00f3tulo": "REPSOL",
            "Tipo Venta": "P",
            "IDEESS": "5989",
            "IDMunicipio": "1220",
            "IDProvincia": "09",
            "IDCCAA": "08"
        },
        {
            "C.P.": "09001",
            "Direcci\u00f3n": "LOPEZ BRAVO, 93",
            "Horario": "L-V: 06:30-22:00; S: 08:00-14:30",
            "Latitud": "42,362528",
            "Localidad": "BURGOS",
            "Longitud (WGS84)": "-3,762083",
            "Margen": "D",
            "Municipio": "Burgos",
            "PrecioProducto": "1,798",
            "Provincia": "BURGOS",
            "Remisi\u00f3n": "dm",
            "R\u00f3tulo": "VILLAL\u00d3N",
            "Tipo Venta": "P",
            "IDEESS": "9803",
            "IDMunicipio": "1220",
            "IDProvincia": "09",
            "IDCCAA": "08"
        },
        {
            "C.P.": "09001",
            "Direcci\u00f3n": "CALLE CONDADO DE TREVI\u00d1O, 30",
            "Horario": "L-D: 06:00-00:00",
            "Latitud": "42,370528",
            "Localidad": "BURGOS",
            "Longitud (WGS84)": "-3,718528",
            "Margen": "I",
            "Municipio": "Burgos",
            "PrecioProducto": "1,792",
            "Provincia": "BURGOS",
            "Remisi\u00f3n": "dm",
            "R\u00f3tulo": "VILLALONQUEJAR",
            "Tipo Venta": "P",
            "IDEESS": "11878",
            "IDMunicipio": "1220",
            "IDProvincia": "09",
            "IDCCAA": "08"
        }
    ]
}
```

You might be using flask and html jinja templates, but here goes with jinja2 Template:

```
>>> from  jinja2 import Template
>>> tm = Template("""
... 
... {% for item in ListaEESSPrecio | sort(attribute=1.PrecioProducto) %}
...     {{ item.Rótulo, item.PrecioProducto, item.Dirección }}
... {%- endfor %}
...
... """)
>>> 
>>> result = tm.render(ListaEESSPrecio=coffee.get('ListaEESSPrecio'))
>>>
>>> print(result)



    ('REPSOL', '1,789', 'CL GENERAL SANZ PASTOR, S.N.')
    ('VILLALÓN', '1,798', 'LOPEZ BRAVO, 93')
    ('VILLALONQUEJAR', '1,792', 'CALLE CONDADO DE TREVIÑO, 30')

>>>
```

Comment: Yeah , I have already sorted using this:
```{% for item in ListaEESSPrecio | sort(attribute='PrecioProducto') %}
    {{ item.Rótulo, item.PrecioProducto, item.Dirección }}
{%- endfor %}```
But that list, all the results of the json, and I want to acces each one alone, because then in another control I saw them individually.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect, providing the desired output?

Comment: I will try to explain it better on the question post